# Ratio problem among A, B and C

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's A , B and C enters into a partnership. A initially invests 25 dollar and add another 10 dollar  after 1 year.  B initially invests 35 dollar  and withdraws  $10  after 2 years.  C invests 30 dollar. In what ratio should the profit be divided?

In this math there is no hints about profit, so how to get the ratio?

> Answer is given :contributions after 3 years as 19:19:18.

Comment: Depends entirely on what their original partnership contract says about division of profits.

Comment: What's the interest rate?

Comment: It;s not given. I guess whatever the interest is, that will be divided into parts according to their investment. right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What they intend you to do is divide the profits according to the number of dollar-years each has invested.  A has $25+35+35=95$, B has $35+35+25=95$, C has $30+30+30=90$.  This produces the desired ratio.  Whether this is fair is not a mathematical question.  Maybe capital was much more valuable in year 1 than in year 3.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot left in the dark with this problem, so Henning Makholm's hint that it actually depends on thepartnership contract is abcolutely correct.

If we assume that profit is generated by money invested in the partnership proportionally to the duration of investment, then we see that $A$ has invested a total of $25+35+35=95$ "year-dollars" during three years (the *three* years seem to appear only in the answer, not the question, however!), $B$ has invested $35+35+25=95$ year-dollars and $C$ has invested $30+30+30=90$ year-dollars.
According to this model, the rations should indeed be $95:95:90=19:19:18$.

However, if there is any profit worth mentioning at all, it can usually assumed to occur at the end of each year, like compound interest. This makes money available in the first year "more valuable" than money available in the last year. As an extreme example, assume there is in fact a *loss* involved: each year the partnership loses two thirds of its capital.
Now if $A$ had *not* made his reinvestment, the original $90\$$ would have become $30\$$after on year, $10\$$ after two years, which $B$ withdraws, yo noting left after three years, whereas *with* $A$'s reinvestment there would atleast be $1.11\$$ left, so why should $B$ and $C$ deserve a share in this?